# Installer, that downloads all the needed files from Internet directly to installation folder

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

So previously, I've used Inno setup to make an Installer.exe and let the users download that, and then install the program. The drawback is, the installer alone is 1.5GB and then after a long install, the user has +3GB of files PLUS the installer in its pc. This method takes a lot of time and hard disk space. I came across Inno Download Plugin, which downloads the files, but it seems to move them to 'tmp' and then copy from there. Is it possible to make IDP move the files directly from web to the path the user has selected as install path? Or is there a better way to achieve this with another software or something?

Answer (score 2):

Inno Download Plugin can download the files anywhere you want, including the installation folder. Of course, you need to schedule the download only after you already know the installation folder. So not in `InitializeWizard` (used usually by IDP examples).

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  { Installation is starting, so we already know what "app" is. }
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    idpAddFile('https://www.example.com/file.zip', ExpandConstant('{app}\file.zip'));

    idpDownloadAfter(wpInstalling);
  end;
end;
```